# Unity Facebook Android SDK doesn't work with signed APK

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I m facing an issue that if I signed my Apk , my facebook login doesn't work correctly.It doesn't not logged me in  . When I removed it I mean select the default option for alias... my facebook login work correctly and i m able to share. Please help me .I m unable to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the hashes for the release keys that you're using to the Facebook app?

If you want to be able to log in using an unsigned build (actually signed with debug keys) and a build signed with release keys you need to add both hashes to the Facebook app.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right .I was forgetting to change the hash when I signed my apk .Actually when u signed apk Facebook gives you new has key to be given on Facebook app.

Comment: If this was the solution can you please accept the answer :)